# Modifying gulp.js to concatenate other JS files into app.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp, zurb-foundation

All,  I'm trying to concatenate the contents of test.js file into my app.js file.  However, I'm not able to do so.  Is there something wrong with syntax?  Thanks for any help.

code of gulp.js file:

```
// 1. LIBRARIES
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

var $        = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var argv     = require('yargs').argv;
var gulp     = require('gulp');
var rimraf   = require('rimraf');
var router   = require('front-router');
var sequence = require('run-sequence');

// Check for --production flag
var isProduction = !!(argv.production);

// 2. FILE PATHS
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

var paths = {
  assets: [
    './client/**/*.*',
    '!./client/templates/**/*.*',
    '!./client/assets/{scss}/**/*.*'
    // '!./client/assets/{scss,js}/**/*.*'
  ],
  // Sass will check these folders for files when you use @import.
  sass: [
    'client/assets/scss',
    'bower_components/foundation-apps/scss'
  ],
  // These files include Foundation for Apps and its dependencies
  foundationJS: [
    'bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js',
    'bower_components/viewport-units-buggyfill/viewport-units-buggyfill.js',
    'bower_components/tether/tether.js',
    'bower_components/hammerjs/hammer.js',
    'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
    'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
    'bower_components/foundation-apps/js/vendor/**/*.js',
    'bower_components/foundation-apps/js/angular/**/*.js',
    '!bower_components/foundation-apps/js/angular/app.js'
  ],
  // These files are for your app's JavaScript
  appJS: [
    'client/assets/js/app.js', 'client/assets/js/modules/test.js'
  ]
}

// 3. TASKS
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

// Cleans the build directory
gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
  rimraf('./build', cb);
});

// Copies everything in the client folder except templates, Sass, and JS
gulp.task('copy', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.assets, {
    base: './client/'
  })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'))
  ;
});

// Copies your app's page templates and generates URLs for them
gulp.task('copy:templates', function() {
  return gulp.src('./client/templates/**')
  // return gulp.src('./client/templates/**/*.html')
    .pipe(router({
      path: 'build/assets/js/routes.js',
      root: 'client'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/templates'))
  ;
});

// Compiles the Foundation for Apps directive partials into a single JavaScript file
gulp.task('copy:foundation', function(cb) {
  gulp.src('bower_components/foundation-apps/js/angular/components/**/*.html')
    .pipe($.ngHtml2js({
      prefix: 'components/',
      moduleName: 'foundation',
      declareModule: false
    }))
    .pipe($.uglify())
    .pipe($.concat('templates.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/js'))
  ;

  // Iconic SVG icons
  gulp.src('./bower_components/foundation-apps/iconic/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/img/iconic/'))
  ;

  cb();
});

// Compiles Sass
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  var minifyCss = $.if(isProduction, $.minifyCss());

  return gulp.src('client/assets/scss/app.scss')
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: paths.sass,
      outputStyle: (isProduction ? 'compressed' : 'nested'),
      errLogToConsole: true
    }))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie 10']
    }))
    .pipe(minifyCss)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/css/'))
  ;
});

// Compiles and copies the Foundation for Apps JavaScript, as well as your app's custom JS
gulp.task('uglify', ['uglify:foundation', 'uglify:app'])

gulp.task('uglify:foundation', function(cb) {
  var uglify = $.if(isProduction, $.uglify()
    .on('error', function (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }));

  return gulp.src(paths.foundationJS)
    .pipe(uglify)
    .pipe($.concat('foundation.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/js/'))
  ;
});

gulp.task('uglify:app', function() {
  var uglify = $.if(isProduction, $.uglify()
    .on('error', function (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }));

  return gulp.src(paths.appJS)
    .pipe(uglify)
    .pipe($.concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/js/'))
  ;
});

// Starts a test server, which you can view at http://localhost:8079
gulp.task('server', ['build'], function() {
  gulp.src('./build')
    .pipe($.webserver({
      port: 8079,
      host: 'localhost',
      fallback: 'index.html',
      livereload: true,
      open: true
    }))
  ;
});

// Builds your entire app once, without starting a server
gulp.task('build', function(cb) {
  sequence('clean', ['copy', 'copy:foundation', 'sass', 'uglify'], 'copy:templates', cb);
});

// Default task: builds your app, starts a server, and recompiles assets when they change
gulp.task('default', ['server'], function () {
  // Watch Sass
  gulp.watch(['./client/assets/scss/**/*', './scss/**/*'], ['sass']);

  // Watch JavaScript
  gulp.watch(['./client/assets/js/**/*', './js/**/*'], ['uglify:app']);

  // Watch static files
  gulp.watch(['./client/**/*.*', '!./client/templates/**/*.*', '!./client/assets/{scss,js}/**/*.*'], ['copy']);

  // Watch app templates
  gulp.watch(['./client/templates/**/*.html'], ['copy:templates']);
});
```

Content of test.js file:

```
app.directive("testConcate", function() {
    return {
        template : '<ul onclick="toggleMenu()"> <li><a ui-sref="designs">Home</a></li>  <li> <a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li> <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li> <li><a ui-sref="contactus">Contact Us</a></li> </ul>'
    };
});
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? I didn't see `gulp-concat` in there anywhere.

Comment: Yes I have executed gulp.js via npm start.  There is a task called, "uglify:app" that is supposed to concate my test.js file but no avail.

Comment: Why not uglify and then use gulp-concat to cat together? There's nothing explicit in the uglify docs about concatenating files together.

Comment: Thanks Chase.  I believe I'm uglifying then concatenating ulp.task('uglify:app', function() {
  var uglify = $.if(isProduction, $.uglify()
    .on('error', function (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }));

  return gulp.src(paths.appJS)
    .pipe(uglify)
    .pipe($.concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/js/'))
  ;
});